# Store a word into a dynamically created array when first encountered

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, comparison

**Here is the assignment:**

Write a program that reads in a text file one word at a time. Store a word into a dynamically created array when it is first encountered. Create a paralle integer array to hold a count of the number of times that each particular word appears in the text file. If the word appears in the text file multiple times, do not add it into your dynamic array, but make sure to increment the corresponding word frequency counter in the parallel integer array. Remove any trailing punctuation from all words before doing any comparisons.

Create and use the following text file containing a quote from Bill Cosby to test your program.

I don't know the key to success, but the key to failure is trying to please everybody.

At the end of your program, generate a report that prints the contents of your two arrays in a format similar to the following:

Word Frequency Analysis

I 1

don't 1

know 1

the 2

key 2

...

**Here is my code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int readInFile (string tempArray [], string file, int arraySize);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string *readInArray = 0,
            *compareArray = 0,
            filename,
            word;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int encountered = 0;
    int j = 0,
        *wordFrequency = 0;


    cout << "Enter the filename you wish to read in: ";
    getline(cin, filename);

    inputFile.open(filename.c_str());

    if (inputFile)
    {
        while (inputFile >> word)
        {
            wordCount++;
        }

        inputFile.close();

        readInArray = new string[wordCount];

        readInFile(readInArray, filename, wordCount);
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Could not open file, ending program";
        return 0;
    }

    compareArray = new string[wordCount];
    wordFrequency = new int[wordCount];

    for (int count = 0; count < wordCount; count++)
        wordFrequency[count] = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; ++i)
    {
        j = 0;
        encountered = 0;

        do
        {
            if (readInArray[i] == compareArray[j])
                encountered = 1;
            ++j;
        } while (j < wordCount);

        if (encountered == 0)
        {
            compareArray[i]=readInArray[i];
            wordFrequency[i] += 1;
        }

    }

    for(int k=0; k < wordCount; ++k)
    {
        cout << "\n" << compareArray[k] << " ";
    }

    for(int l=0; l < wordCount; ++l)
    {
        cout << "\n" << wordFrequency[l] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}


int readInFile (string tempArray [], string file, int arraySize)
{
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open(file.c_str());

    if (inputFile)
    {
        cout << "\nHere is the text file:\n\n";

        for(int i=0; i < arraySize; ++i)
        {
            inputFile >> tempArray[i];
            cout << tempArray[i] << " ";
        }

        inputFile.close();
    } 
}
```

**Here is my question:**

How do you store a word into a dynamically created array when it is first encountered? As you can see from my code made a string array with some of the elements empty. I believe it is suppose to be done using pointers.

Also how do I get rid of the punctuation in the string array? Should it be converted to a c-string first? But then how would I compare the words without converting back to a string array?

**Here is a link to a java program that does something similar:**

http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes3/c10/ex-10-1-answer.html

Thank you for any help you can offer!!

Comment: I do not think that an array is a good option.
Try [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) or [std::unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)

Comment: For the class I am in we have not covered those topic yet. Why would using an array not be a good option?

Comment: Take the Java tag off

Comment: @voodoochild96 Array is not good because it is static by definition. Something like "dynamic array" has very bad performance or is very hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

As to the first part of your question, you are not using a dynamically created array. You are using a regular array. C++ provides implementations of dymnamic arrays, like the vector class  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

As to the second part of your question, I see no reason to convert it to a c string. The string class in c++ provides functionality for removing and searching for characters. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

The string::erase function can be used to erase punctuation characters found with string::find.

Note: There are other ways of doing this assignment that may be easier (like having an array of structs containing a string and an int, or using a map) but that may defeat the purpose of the assignment.